# *-Groups or "Group with Involution"?

Tags: group-theory

Wikipedia has a basic [reference on *-rings in the *-algebra article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*-algebra#*-ring), which defines a *-ring as a ring equipped with a `*` operator which is an antiautomorphism and an involution.

However, I am not interested in rings equipped with such an operator, but Groups equipped with one.  I tried searching for "*-group" to find references, but wasn't able to find much (I also tried the groupified versions of the alternative names Wikipedia suggested for *-rings: "involutive ring, involutory ring, and ring with involution", with no luck).

I am wondering if such a structure as a "*-group" exists in the literature, and if so, what name does it go by?

Is there some reference that could give a basic introduction to the subject? (Or maybe the structure is trivial, which might explain so little has been written about it?)

(For the context of why I am interested, I am thinking about generalizations of a [Counted B-Tree](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/cbtree.html) for non-commutative sums, where segments can be added together, subtracted off from each other, and "flipped" to reverse the order).

Comment: Wikipedia may not have an article on $*$-groups, but it does have an article on the broader class of [$*$-semigroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*-semigroup).